# Restart Server - Linux

Tags: linux, ssl

I have a CentOS Linux 6.5 server. I need to make changes to

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

(to configure the ciphers).

**Question**

Once I have changed `ssl.conf`, do I need to restart the server?  How?

I have tried the following, but it does not seem to work.

```
[jboss@primary ssl]$ systemctl restart httpd
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  jboss
 2.  rembun
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): Failed to restart httpd.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status httpd.service' for details.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/jboss
[jboss@primary ssl]$ 1
-bash: 1: command not found
[jboss@primary ssl]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user jboss has Sudo privileges, I would run the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

This will prevent the SystemD Authentication prompt asking for credentials, and instead just prompt for the user’s password.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Silly me. I will mark this as the answer

Comment: No problem, we’ve all been there...

Answer (score 2):

You need to reload the Apache service.
You can do that with: `sudo systemctl reload httpd`

Restarting the Apache service would also do the trick (as you tried to do in your stdout pasted above).

Restarting the entire server would also do the trick, but that would be overkill.

Are you sure that this is a CentOS 6.5 machine? Systemd (which provides the `systemctl` command) wasn't introduced until RHEL / CentOS 7.

In your above output, the reason it didn't work is because you didn't use sudo.
You need to do something like this: `sudo systemctl restart httpd` instead of simply `systemctl restart httpd`